# How to enable 7680 x 4320 resolution with my GTX 1080?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, display-resolution

- Ubuntu 22.04
- NVIDIA drivers 525
- NVIDIA GTX 1080
- Samsung QN850A    8k

So I realize it's an older card, but I would like to get the 8k going, and the manufacturer specs say this is supported:

https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-1080/specifications/

However, when I go into Display Properties, no 8k option is specified.  The list tops out at 4096x2160 (5k I guess?) which looks terrible, so I am currently stuck with 3840x2160.

**Update**: Have not been able to get 8k off my 1080, even after getting HDMI 2.1 "8k" cables and a not-cheap DisplayPort-to-HDMI converter.  However, the the Samsung *does* display full 8k from my 3080Ti in a different machine.  Notably though you have to go into Samsung `External Device Manager > Input Signal Plus` settings and enable this, 8k is not enabled by default for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GTX 1080 only supports 8k output on it's DisplayPort port, not HDMI. There are no DisplayPort inputs on the QN850A, so even though the TV may support 8k input via HDMI, the GTX 1080 would not be able to drive the TV at 8k over HDMI.

You cannot (easily) convert a DisplayPort 8k signal to an HDMI 8k signal. There is also little to suggest that the Samsung QN850A even supports 8k video input anyway, with all of the marketing suggesting 4k to 8k upscaling.

[Edit] Here is the spec page for the TV: https://www.samsung.com/us/televisions-home-theater/tvs/samsung-neo-qled-8k/75-qn800a-neo-qled-8k-smart-tv-2021-qn75qn800afxza/#specs

https://content.syndigo.com/asset/85895d30-38ab-4567-81d2-2c066884c7f3/original.pdf

Comment: Ok thanks very much for this.  I would note though, the specs page you showed me does say that it has 7680x4320 resolution and "real 8k", but it did not occur to me that these things could be different.  I will look into DP/HDMI conversion.